# trying to use @media to hide print button

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp
```

In my .cshtml page using the above link to use @media.

Although when i insert the code (below) it flags @media saying does not exist in the context. why is this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
  }
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
@media screen,print
  {
  p.test {font-weight:bold;}
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Razor syntax? You will need to escape the @ symbol

```
<style>
@@media screen
  {
  p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
  }
@@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
@@media screen,print
  {
  p.test {font-weight:bold;}
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

As correctly answered already you would need to escape the @ symbol.  But I would question in the first place why you have in-line styles in a view.

Best practice is to keep your page styles in a style sheet, then your problem disappears!

Answer (score 1):

The Razor engine is interpreting `@media` as code. Try escaping the `@`:

`@@media screen`